# Print array with alternate colour in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array,

```
$arr = arrary("Pune","Nashik","Mumbai");
```

I want to display `Pune` in red colour, then on the next line `Nashik` will be blue and the last line will have `Mumbai` in green. How do I do this using a "**while loop**".

Like,

```
Pune (in red) 
Nashik (in blue) 
Mumbai (in green)
```

Comment: Is this being displayed in HTML? Or in a terminal window that supports colors?

Comment: @sberry2A - php suggests HTML

Comment: @Graphain not always, PHP scripts can be written for use with the command line

Comment: This is blatant homework with no attempt shown by the OP (who has no rep). Vote to close.

Comment: @mc10 - Sure, but I said *suggests*.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply build the logic into the array, eg

```
$arr = array(
    'Pune'   => '#ff0000',
    'Nashik' => '#0000ff',
    'Mumbai' => '#00ff00'
);
```

Then, when you loop over it, use CSS to display the colours.

```
<?php foreach ($arr as $something => $colour) : ?>
    <p style="color:<?php echo $colour ?>"><?php echo $something ?></p>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

You could also use CSS class names instead of hex colour values.

Also, a `while` loop is hardly the best option for iterating over an array.

**Edit:** Oops, accidentally deleted my second example. It's back now